# Adding CartoDB map in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: carto, openlayers

I'm trying to add a CartoDB basemap to my OpenLayers 3 map and then a province layer afterwards. I already read [Adding CartoDB basemap in OpenLayers 3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/171734/115) and it was very useful but I created my own map in CartoDB and I want to add it to Openlayers 3.

Here are links to my [CartoDB map](https://final-arash.cartodb.com/viz/ee9e7f42-d850-11e5-89c5-0e3ff518bd15/public_map) and my [CartoDB.js](https://final-arash.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/ee9e7f42-d850-11e5-89c5-0e3ff518bd15/viz.json).

Comment: As a new user please take the [Tour] to learn about the site. Thanks and other words of appreciation should not be included in your questions and answers - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/215590 - think of our Q&As as being wiki pages rather than personal communications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a complete example of using Openlayers3 with CartoDB.js [here](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/develop/examples/openlayers3.html).

Comment: Can you add in your answer the link to the running demo itself using RawGit e.g http://rawgit.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/develop/examples/openlayers3.html? End users can view the result, not only the code itself.